# Interstitial change admob to MobFox

Tags: android, admob, interstitial, mobfox

I have a source code with interstitial admob, I've changed Interstitial MobFox, the game runs but does not show interstitial

I put the code used to generate the interstitial, to help me

```
import com.adsdk.sdk.Ad;
import com.adsdk.sdk.AdListener;
import com.adsdk.sdk.AdManager;
import com.adsdk.sdk.Gender;
import com.adsdk.sdk.banner.AdView;
...

public class MainGame extends Screen {
...
//ad
private AdManager mManager;
int ad_counter = 0;
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
//setDebugMode(true);
//initialiseAccelerometer();

//highscores
highscoreManager = new HighScoreManager(this, savedInstanceState, layout);

// Create the interstitial

mManager = new AdManager(this,"http://my.mobfox.com/request.php",
"fe96717d9875b9da4339ea5367eff1ec", true);


//interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, getResources().getString(R.string.InterstitialAd_unit_id));

}

public void openAd() {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
// Create ad request

mManager.requestAd();

    }
    });
 }
...

public synchronized void GameOver() {
if (ad_counter >= getResources().getInteger(R.integer.add_shows_every_X_gameovers)) {
mManager.showAd();//TODO: Remove openAd(); to stop interstatial ads.
ad_counter = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not call openAd funtion. Try

```
import com.adsdk.sdk.Ad;
import com.adsdk.sdk.AdListener;
import com.adsdk.sdk.AdManager;
import com.adsdk.sdk.Gender;
import com.adsdk.sdk.banner.AdView;
...

public class MainGame extends Screen {
...
//ad
private AdManager mManager;
int ad_counter = 0;
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
//setDebugMode(true);
//initialiseAccelerometer();

//highscores
highscoreManager = new HighScoreManager(this, savedInstanceState, layout);

// Create the interstitial

mManager = new AdManager(this,"http://my.mobfox.com/request.php",
"fe96717d9875b9da4339ea5367eff1ec", true);
mManager.requestAd();

}


public synchronized void GameOver() {
if (ad_counter >= getResources().getInteger(R.integer.add_shows_every_X_gameovers)) {
mManager.showAd();//TODO: Remove openAd(); to stop interstatial ads.
ad_counter = 0;
}
```